# Rails redis cache storage size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

I have rails app storing values to redis cache through a cron job overnight. But some values stored is showing as nil when I have checked in the morning.
What is the storage size/limit of redis cache in rails?
How can I change this value through configuration and runtime?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#configuration)

You can set up your application's default cache store by setting the config.cache_store configuration option. Other parameters can be passed as arguments to the cache store's constructor:

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }
```

Alternatively, you can call ActionController::Base.cache_store outside of a configuration block.

You can access the cache by calling Rails.cache.